# Why this PowerShell alias does not work?

Tags: powershell, alias

I am learning PowerShell.

I would like to understand why some aliases in PowerShell 5.0 under Windows 8.1 do not work.

For instance, this command alone works:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT
```

But it does not when defined in my `$profile` as follows:

```
Set-Alias -Name wei -Value 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT'
```

The error message follows:

> ```
> PS C:\> wei
> wei : The term 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT' is not recognized as the 
> name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
> or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
> included, verify that the path is correct and
> try again.
> At line:1 char:1
> + wei
> + ~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
> ```

**EDIT:**

I see the aliases work a little different than in standard Bash on Linux I am used to.

The solution was to simply declare it as a function:

```
Function wei { Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT }
```

Comment: Your alias equivalent to `& 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like to pass other parameters to your alias, you can do this:

```
function wei([Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true)]$params) {
    & Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT $params
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally PowerShell tries to use the first space to separate the command from the parameters.  However, you can use a string to specify that a space is just part of a file.  This essentially lets you treat the space like a non-special character, and allows you to treat something like 'C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\notepad.exe' as if it was one word, not two.

That's essentially what you're doing.  PowerShell cannot find a command named 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT', because there is no such command.  (The command in question is simply 'Get-WmiObject', not 'Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT'.

Comment: So, I have now identified the problem.  I realize I haven't provided a workaround/solution.  Being that I am supposed to be at work in less than 5 hours and should get some more sleep before then, I will allow someone else that pleasure.  Hopefully my comment helped identify the right track of what needed to be solved.